# Calculate the size of a shadow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shadow

I created a Unity3d project and I used some spotlights behind objects to get their shadows. I'm trying to get the real size (using my scale) of the shadow once reflected on the floor. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do believe your question would mostly belong to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) but here's an approach that I hope will lead you to the right direction.

The hypotheses I took here are:

- you know your object height when scale = 1
- your object isn't too large on its top (or you will have to include half its width to the maths)
- your object pivot is placed at it's base (on a human : under its feet)
- your object is placed on the floor (and therefore not in the air: otherwise it's a bit more complicated to calculate but the idea remains the same)

Here's a quick schema of the situation:
[image]

Now you can calculate your shadow's size using something like this:

```
Vector3 topPoint = YOUR_OBJECT.transform.position + YOUR_OBJECT.transform.lossyScale.y * YOUR_OBJECT_HEIGHT;
Vector3 lightFlatPoint = new Vector3(YOUR_LIGHT.transform.position.x, topPoint.y, YOUR_LIGHT.transform.position.z);

float lightDeltaY = YOUR_LIGHT.transform.position.y - topPoint.y;
float lightFlatToTopPointDistance = Vector3.Distance(lightFlatPoint, topPoint);

float shadowSize = ((YOUR_OBJECT.transform.lossyScale.y * YOUR_OBJECT_HEIGHT) / lightDeltaY) * lightFlatToTopPointDistance;
```

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: I love these drawing from developers :D +1 for that

Comment: Thanks for it ! (for once I used shapes and not hand drawing... I bet you can guess why considering my artistic talents :P )